# Query about Intent.ACTION_VIEW in android

Tags: android

In   Intent.ACTION_VIEW   what  is  Intent?  Is  it  a  class or  method  and  here  what  is  ACTION_VIEW  ? is  it  a  variable  and  what  is  the  type  of  it's ? please explain in details. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Intent` in android is an `abstract public Class`. `ACTION_VIEW` is the action on Intent.

```
public static final String ACTION_VIEW
```

> Since: API Level 1 Activity Action: Display the data to the user. This
>   is the most common action performed on data -- it is the generic
>   action you can use on a piece of data to get the most reasonable thing
>   to occur. For example, when used on a contacts entry it will view the
>   entry; when used on a mailto: URI it will bring up a compose window
>   filled with the information supplied by the URI; when used with a tel:
>   URI it will invoke the dialer.
>
> Input: getData() is URI from which to retrieve data.
>
> Output: nothing.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.VIEW"

You need to read the developers guide for Android. You will get a better understanding [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 1):

Intent is a public class that is most commonly used to start new Activities. For instance:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I'd recommend reading the Android Development manual, and trying a couple easy tutorials to get started. You can find that here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

This page will describe ACTION_VIEW and Intent in detail; much better than I can: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Hope it helps.